# Non-Projective Example

Tags: computational-linguistics, grammar

I'm looking for an example sentence with a non-projective dependency parse. 
It doesn't have to be in English, though such an example would be nice.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: I think you'll have to indicate what **you** mean by a "sentence with a non-projective dependency parse", because that's not really a standard term, no matter what your professors said. An example would be nice, especially if it contrasted with an example of a sentence that was minimally distinct in that it **does** have a projective dependency parse, or a non-projective non-dependency parse, or something else that would allow triangulation.

Answer (score 8):

The paper, [Non-projective Dependency Parsing using Spanning Tree Algorithms](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~strctlrn/bib/PDF/nonprojectiveHLT-EMNLP2005.pdf) has a few examples of non-projective dependency trees.

[image: non projective tree]

Note that dependency graphs are (1) not a formalism and (2) not standardized, so each researcher may re-define what happens in dependencies. Some of those dependency graphs are not even trees. Refer [Generating Typed Dependency Parses from Phrase Structure Parses](http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/LREC06_dependencies.pdf).

[image: dependency graph]

Comment: how do you draw these trees in LaTeX??

Comment: @CpILL I'm not really big on LaTeX but you can look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics

Comment: @prash So the first sentence is non-projective only because of word 'yesterday'?

Comment: @Amir: It's a combination of two factors, 'yesterday' and 'which was a Yorkshire Terrier'.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different way to look at it: you draw the dependency tree above the sentence with each node aligned with the corresponding word in the sentence, draw a line between the words in the tree and their correspondent in the sentence, and check whether there are any lines intersecting.

The structure below is for the French sentence *À qui veux-tu que Pierre parle ?* (lit. *To whom want you that Peter talks?*, 'Who do you want Peter to talk to?'). This sentence is non-projective because *à qui* has sort of "emancipated" from its governor to position itself relatively to *veux*. The dependency between *parle* and *à* crosses three node projections.

[image]

Comment: Yes, nice example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short English example from the paper [Non-Projective Dependency Parsing in Expected Linear Time](https://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~nivre/docs/acl09.pdf):

[image: Dependency tree for an English sentence (non-projective).]

Or, if you want it in [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/),

[image: Universal Dependencies non-projective tree for an English sentence.]

Here is the LaTeX code to generate the latter:

```
\begin{dependency}
    \begin{deptext}[column sep=1.2em]
        A \& hearing \& is \& scheduled \& on \& the \& issue \& today \\
    \end{deptext}
    \deproot{4}{root}
    \depedge{2}{1}{det}
    \depedge{4}{2}{nsubj:pass}
    \depedge{4}{3}{aux:pass}
    \depedge{7}{5}{case}
    \depedge{7}{6}{det}
    \depedge[edge start x offset=-6pt]{2}{7}{nmod}
    \depedge[edge slant=6pt]{4}{8}{nmod:tmod}
\end{dependency}
```